# Generating a ckan.ini file. 'ckan' not found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ckan

I'm having issues going through the installation process for ckan from source. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my computer. Whenever I reach the point of generating a ckan.ini file, I get such an error:

```
Command 'ckan' not found, did you mean

command 'ckon' from deb ckon
command 'cpan' from deb perl

Try: sudo apt install
```

I honestly don't know what the problem is. Please help me. I cloned the github stable release and it all worked well until this point where I have to generate a `ckan.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the virtual environment with:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
```

As per docs: https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#install-ckan-into-a-python-virtual-environment